# Disabling the On-click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a table row which specifies an onclick event as follows.

```
onclick="dispStudRequest('<%=u_studentRequestID%>','<%=rollno%>')"
```

And there are many table data in the table row and there are multiple rows as well.

Here my requirement is to disable this onclick event only on one table data but keep it active for the whole row.

Is there any was to disable the onclick event for only one table data.

**Edit**

Table shown below.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function dispStudRequest(val, val1)
{
    document.location.href="/student/Studentdetails.jsp?u_StudentID="+val+"&u_rollnoNumber="+val1;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr onclick="dispStudRequest('<%=u_studentRequestID%>','<%=rollno%>')">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxVer" value="<%=seqno%>" onClick="return checkClick(this);" CHECKED></td>
    <td><img style="width="15" height="15"; <%=iSrc%>></td>
    <td>Student1</td>

</tr>
<tr onclick="dispStudRequest('<%=u_studentRequestID%>','<%=rollno%>')">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxVer" value="<%=seqno%>" onClick="return checkClick(this);" CHECKED></td>
    <td><img style="width="15" height="15"; <%=iSrc%>></td>
    <td>Student2</td>

</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And the onclick event needs to be disabled on first **`<td>`** which is a **checkbox**.

Comment: Sure there is, but as you've left out just about all the HTML, we don't know what classes, id's or other attributes this row has ?

Comment: @adeneo : Table sample added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign a class that has the following rule:

`.off { pointer-events: none; }`

to any element rendering it unclickable.

Use a class to enable click when desired:

`.on { pointer-events: auto; }`

The snippet demonstrates this by entering a number <kbd>1 to 4</kbd> then <kbd>off or on</kbd>

```js
function toggleTD(pos, state) {
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  var tgt = anchors[pos - 1];
  if (state === 'on') {
    tgt.classList.remove('off');
    tgt.classList.add('on');
  } else {
    tgt.classList.add('off');
    tgt.classList.remove('on');
  }
  return false;
}

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var inp1 = document.getElementById('inp1').value;
  var inp2 = document.getElementById('inp2').value;
  return toggleTD(inp1, inp2);
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: calc(50% - .5em);
  display: block;
}
.on {
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: green;
}
.off {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: red;
}
input {
  width: 2em;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/">CLICK</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="/">CLICK</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="/">CLICK</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="/">CLICK</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<label>Position</label>
<input id="inp1">
<label>On/Off</label>
<input id="inp2">
<button id="btn">ToggleTD</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `onclick="return false"` to disable clicks and `oncontextmenu="return false"` to disable right-clicks.

Eg.

```
<table onclick="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
  <tr onclick="dispStudRequest('<%=u_studentRequestID%>','<%=rollno%>')">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxVer" value="<%=seqno%>" onClick="return checkClick(this);" CHECKED></td>
    <td><img style="width="15" height="15"; <%=iSrc%>></td>
    <td>Student1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="dispStudRequest('<%=u_studentRequestID%>','<%=rollno%>')">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxVer" value="<%=seqno%>" onClick="return checkClick(this);" CHECKED></td>
    <td><img style="width="15" height="15"; <%=iSrc%>></td>
    <td>Student2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```